Как изменить путь сохранения фото в Wordpress?
Знаю можно добавить фильтр:
function custom_upload_dir( $uploads ) {
    $time = current_time( 'mysql' );
    $uploads['subdir'] = '/' . substr( $time, 0, 4 ) . '/' . substr( $time, 5, 2 ) . '/' . substr( $time, 8, 2 );
    $uploads['path'] = $uploads['basedir'] . $uploads['subdir'];
    $uploads['url'] = $uploads['baseurl'] . $uploads['subdir'];
    return $uploads;
}

Но проблема в том что берется текущее время, мне же нужно сделать так чтобы использовалась дата загрузки который я передаю при загрузке скриптом python.
Все что нашел в интернете это обходные пути сохранять привязывая к посту, но для меня это не вариант.

дубликат?

@aleksandr-barakin нет, там вопрос был в механизме отправки из python в Wordpress, с тем вопросом я разобрался, теперь нужно исправить сам механизм сохранения уже в Wordpress на сервере, потому как моя идея сработала, но все равно Wordpress сохраняет используя текущую дату и время в качестве части пути, не смотря на то что принимает от python другую дату.

Ну так эта другая дата откуда возьмется?
